# Add a new feature to existing rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have recently downloaded a new project(open source),i found certain features missing like blog,forum ,chat etc.. ..so I like to add those features to the project .My problem if run `rails forum` it will create a new rails project but i want to add to the existing project. I have found business logic. . . .
I had created models

```
ruby script/generate model forum 
ruby script/generate model topic
ruby script/generate model post
rake db:migrate
ruby script/generate migration add_foreign_to_topics forum_id:integer
ruby script/generate migration add_foreign_to_post topic_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Then i ran

```
ruby script/generate controller forum
```

it was asking should i overwrite or not,so i am stuck up here,i need to create a controller and view for this feature.I am following this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/building-a-forum-from-scratch-with-ruby-on-rails/ and i have already user table etc..

Answer (score 3):

As far as i can read, you are not following the tutorial, as it does a scaffold which generates the controller and models at the same time.

Either you do something like

```
ruby script/generate scaffold Forum title:string contents:text
```

and it generates the model, controller, routes and views for you. In the tutorial they use `nifty_scaffold` and i think it mostly improves the view.

If you create the models seperately, you need to do something like

```
ruby script/generate controller Forum index show create edit update new destroy
```

and then you will have to fill in all those actions yourself. You will also have to set your routes correctly. That is not bad and not at all difficult. But when you are starting, using the `scaffold` is much easier.